# Ubuntu running Multiple .service files

Tags: php, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I want to run two different services at two different ports at a Ubuntu VPS. For this purpose I created two different service files 
/etc/systemd/system/myfirst-server.service 
and 
/etc/systemd/system/mysecond-server.service

These files are

```
  [Unit]
  Description=Chat Server

  [Service]
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/path1/bin/myfirst-server.php
  StandardOutput=null
  Restart=always
  RestartSec=10

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and

```
  [Unit]
  Description=Chat Server

  [Service]
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/path2/bin/mysecond-server.php
  StandardOutput=null
  Restart=always
  RestartSec=10

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I am running them by

```
sudo systemctl enable myfirst-server.service
sudo systemctl enable mysecond-server.service

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl start myfirst-server.service
sudo systemctl start mysecond-server.service
```

Now the issue is if I run one of them it work perfectly well but with two of the they start behaving unpredictably- at one time they run good at other time one does not run. Strangely enough both of them respond to WSS connecting perfectly well.

Any help about how to run two services

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/path1/bin/myfirst-server.php
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/path2/bin/mysecond-server.php
```

simultaneously is highly appreciated

Comment: This question is probably better at SuperUser than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of testing it turned out to be that this is how we are supposed to do the task. The issue was somewhere else. Actually both of my servers were using MySQL connections and turned out to be that MySQL was taking timeout and disconnecting after 8 hours of inactivity. So for now I have fixed it by adding cron jobs as root which use systemctl to restart the services after 8 hours. It is working for me. As I get more load on my server the solution will also evolve. 
Thanks